# Does MySQL have a a COPY TO command like Postgres?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Postgres's COPY TO and COPY FROM make dumping and loading of files very fast as compared to one-row-at-a-time reading/writing.
Is there a similar feature for MySQL?

Comment: Yes, LOAD DATA: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks. Just found: LOAD DATA and SELECT INTO OUTFILE do the same thing as COPY FROM and COPY TO.
Please put this as an answer so that I can accept it and make it available for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) / [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).